# Where's The Circular Dependency?

Tags: typescript, tsyringe

I'm writing a CLI using TSyringe and getting an error. I'm not exactly sure I know why.

```
Error: Attempted to construct an undefined constructor. Could mean a circular dependency problem. Try using `delay` function.
```

Here's the code:

```js
//--- loco

#!/usr/bin/env node

const process = require('process')
const Locomotion = require('../dist')
const ts = require('tsyringe')

async function main() {
  //const loco = new Locomotion.Locomotion()
  //console.log(ts.container)
  const client = ts.container.resolve(Locomotion)
  await client.init()
  await client.start()
}

main()
  .then(() => {
    process.exit(0)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err) // Writes to stderr
    process.exit(1)
  })

//--- index.ts (called by loco)

import 'reflect-metadata'
import { container } from 'tsyringe'
import { Locomotion } from './Locomotion'
import { ConfigurationReader } from './ConfigurationReader'

container.register('ConfigurationReaderInterface', {
  useClass: ConfigurationReader,
})

export { Locomotion }

//--- Locomotion.ts

import { inject, injectable } from 'tsyringe'
import { ConfigurationReaderInterface } from './interfaces/ConfigInterfaces'

@injectable()
export class Locomotion {
  constructor(@inject('ConfigurationReaderInterface') private _reader: ConfigurationReaderInterface) {}

  public async init() {
    console.log('init')
  }

  public async start() {
    console.log('start')
  }
}

//--- ConfigurationReader.ts

import { ConfigurationInterface, ConfigurationReaderInterface } from './interfaces/ConfigInterfaces'

export class ConfigurationReader implements ConfigurationReaderInterface {
  _config?: ConfigurationInterface | null

  constructor() {
    this._config = null
  }

  public async load() {}
}

//--- ConfigInterfaces.ts

type SuffixPairType = {
  up: string
  down: string
}

interface ConfigurationInterface {
  name: string
  aliases: Array<string>
  migrationPath: string
  suffixes: SuffixPairType
  dialect: string
  host: string
  port: number
  database: string
  schema: string
  user: string
  password: string
}

interface ConfigurationReaderInterface {
  load(): void
}

export { SuffixPairType, ConfigurationInterface, ConfigurationReaderInterface }
```